# Display Sorted Column on Static Page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

I am creating a website that allows users to evaluate their coworkers. My boss would like the averages to be displayed from best to worst on a static page that she can print and hang up in our store, so the employees can see their results compared to other employees. I have been searching for awhile now on how to easily sort a column. I found a Railscast on sorting columns, but it seems a lot more detailed than I truly need. I found the order API, but I don't think I'm implementing it the way I need to. I am hoping that maybe there is a one-liner that can help me solve this problem, such as:

```
@user = User.all.order(average: :asc)
```

Where I can load a static page that prints the user's name and their score. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does the users table actually have an `average` column? Seems to me that average should be a calculated value, otherwise, you're kind of defeating the purpose of an RDBMS (and it also affects the answer to your question).

Comment: Yes, each user has their own individual, overall score that is stored in the database. I would like to sort all of those scores from best to worst. Is there some API that can sort that information without actually trying to sort a database column? If so, that works too, I'm just very new to rails, HTML, etc. It just seems that sorting a column of averages might be easier than doing it within the code, but that's why I am asking. From the Railscast I saw, it seems that there isn't a built in method that will sort ascending, but I might be overlooking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried that code of yours? It should do exactly what you're asking except from lowest score to highest score.

You could simplify it a little and sort from highest to lowest by doing:

```
@users = User.order(average: :desc)
```

Like MarsAtomic said, this assumes that you actually have a column in your users table called `average`. If not we need more information on how your database is set up.

Comment: Ah, that was the mistake. I had made average a variable that was the average of 5 different columns, but I will just make a column that stores that information into the database! Thank you so much for clarifying!